# How to share a USB drive over SMB/CIFS on an ADSL router?

Tags: linux

I found many posts online about my problem and similar, but none of them could help me to solve it.

I want to share, in my domestic net, a USB pendrive to plug
into the router.  From the web GUI router the device is seen,
also with the free and busy space on it.  But when I try to
mount and see it from the PC, I get errors:

```
$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.1
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter rodolfo's password: 
Connection to 192.168.1.1 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
```

and

```
# mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /mnt/public
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage:  
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I don't know what to do.  Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your router is located at 192.168.1.1?

Comment: To access it via web GUI, I type that string in the address bar of the browser

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem.  There remain though problems with latin accented vowels: they are not properly encoded in the partition which is on the drive.  Please help who can with this issue.  Meanwhile, I here report the procedure I've followed.

Router model: Technicolor TG582n.  See:

https://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?p=4603163

I plugged the USB drive into the USB port of the router.  Before being mounted
on PC's filesystem, the drive has to be mounted by the router itself.  To do
that, point web browser to:

192.168.1.1

, Username and password both `admin'.  Then,

Toolbox -> Content Sharing

.  Up right, there is

Overview | Configure

.  Click on Configure and set up the partition as a `Managed partition'.  This
way, the drive is mounted on the router.  (When later you'll want to unplug the
drive, first you have to unmount it from the router: from Configure, click on
Stop.)  Note that, in Content Sharing, there is:

Server IP address: 192.168.1.2

.  Then,

$ nautilus smb://192.168.1.2

and you'll see the two directories Media and Shared.  Then,

# aptitude install cifs-utils
 # mkdir /mnt/public

, then put in /etc/fstab the following line:

//192.168.1.2/Shared /mnt/public cifs rw,user,noauto       0       0

After that, you can mount the drive as a normal user with:

$ mount /mnt/public

, hitting Enter when asked for password.

$ cd /mnt/public

The directory is empty, but doesn't matter.  On the drive, two directories have
been mysteriously created: `Media' and`Shared': now you are in Shared.  You
can now write onto it.

From Help -> Toolbox -> Content Sharing:

"If a drive or partition is selected as managed partition, users will only be
able to access following folders:

Media

Shared

If these folders are not on your USB storage device, the Technicolor Gateway
will create them automatically. All other folders will be hidden from the
user."